# I can not open a Visual Studio Code workspace using new application link syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am trying to simplify and standardize my team's .code-workspace files and repository linking.  Furthermore, I'd love to be able to link a local GitLab-hosted .code-workspace file to have a 'one click' option to clone a git repo, link VS Code to that repo, etc, all through the .code-workspace configuration file.

Step 1 of this workflow would be to be able to open workspaces via application links, which was just released in 1.43 in February 2020.

Per [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_open-workspaces-via-application-links), I see the syntax:

```
vscode://file/<file-path>
```

I am not able to get any of the following to open the actual .code-workspace file as expected:

```
vscode://example.code-workspace/E:\GitLabProjects\workspace-automation\
vscode://file/E:\GitLabProjects\workspace-automation\example.code-workspace
vscode://E:\GitLabProjects\workspace-automation\example.code-workspace\
vscode://file/E:\GitLabProjects\workspace-automation\example.code-workspace\
vscode://E:\GitLabProjects\workspace-automation\example.code-workspace
vscode://https://my.repo.com@SSL/path/to/file/example.code-workspace
vscode://file/https://my.repo.com@SSL/path/to/file/example.code-workspace
```

Most of these syntax test **DO** open VS Code, but not the workspace file.

Is anyone use this feature yet, or have more insight into the details of how this new thing works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be supported with [microsoft/vscode issue 63735](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63735) but...

I can open VSCode 1.43 and the workspace *file* with:

```
vscode://file/E:/GitLabProjects/workspace-automation/example.code-workspace
```

However, I still have to click on an "Open workspace" button after that.

[image: open workspace in VSCode]

Comment: Thank you @VonC.  I do believe i tried this exact syntax, but I would have completely missed seeing that button.  I've never opened a workspace file itself in VS Code, so I was not expecting that.

Comment: this worked for me but I use to be able to open workspaces automatically and not have to mess with this. not sure what happened